# Spring UnsatisfiedDependencyException Problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I tried to create a simple connection to AWS DynamoDB, but unfortunately run into some issues with Spring. I setup the profile with my connection credentials from Amazon and configured this Profile as default. Now when I'm trying to start the application it always shows me the following errors. I guess its something with the class path, but I couldn't find a solution.

The goal of this exercise should be to post some Data on the database.

In Addition my classes:

```
package com.example.mfc;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class DynamoDBConfig {

    @Value("${amazon.access.key}")
    private String awsAccessKey;

    @Value("${amazon.access.secret-key}")
    private String awsSecretKey;

    @Value("${amazon.region}")
    private String awsRegion;

    @Value("${amazon.end-point.url}")
    private String awsDynamoDBEndPoint;

    @Bean
    public DynamoDBMapper mapper(){
        return new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDBConfig());
    }

    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDBConfig(){
        return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(awsDynamoDBEndPoint, awsRegion))
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey)))
                .build();
    }
}






package com.example.mfc;

import com.example.classes.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dynamoDb")
public class DynamoDBController {

    @Autowired
    private DynamoDBRepository repository;

    @PostMapping
    public String insertUserIntoDynamoDb(@RequestBody User user){
        repository.insertUserIntoDynamoDB(user);
        return "User successfully inserted into DynamoDB table.";
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<User> getOneUserDetail(@RequestParam String UserID, @RequestParam String lastName){
        User user = repository.getOneUserDetail(UserID, lastName);
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PutMapping
    public void updateUserDetail(@RequestBody User user){
        repository.updateUserDetail(user);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "{userID}/{lastName}")
    public void deleteUserDetail(@PathVariable("userID") String userID, @PathVariable("lastName") String lastName){
        User user = new User();
        user.setUserID(userID);
        user.setLastName(lastName);
        repository.deleteUserDetail(user);
    }
}






package com.example.mfc;

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBSaveExpression;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ComparisonOperator;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ConditionalCheckFailedException;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ExpectedAttributeValue;
import com.example.classes.User;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@Repository
public class DynamoDBRepository {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(DynamoDBRepository.class);

    @Autowired
    private DynamoDBMapper mapper;

    public void insertUserIntoDynamoDB(User user){
        mapper.save(user);
    }

    public User getOneUserDetail(String userID, String lastName){
        return mapper.load(User.class, userID, lastName);
    }

    public void updateUserDetail(User user) {
        try {
            mapper.save(user, buildDynamoDBSaveExpression(user));
        } catch (ConditionalCheckFailedException exception) {
            LOGGER.info("invalid data. -" + exception.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void deleteUserDetail(User user){
        mapper.delete(user);
    }

    public DynamoDBSaveExpression buildDynamoDBSaveExpression(User user){
        DynamoDBSaveExpression saveExpression = new DynamoDBSaveExpression();
        Map<String, ExpectedAttributeValue> expected = new HashMap<>();
        expected.put("userID", new ExpectedAttributeValue(new AttributeValue(user.getUserID()))
                .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ));
        saveExpression.setExpected(expected);
        return saveExpression;
    }
}





package com.example.mfc;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MfcApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MfcApplication.class, args);
    }
}





package com.example.classes;

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "MFC")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String userID;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "UserID")
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    @DynamoDBRangeKey
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}


2022-09-01 21:15:06.521  INFO 39924 --- [           main] com.example.mfc.MfcApplication           : Starting MfcApplication using Java 14.0.2 on Andreass-MBP-2 with PID 39924 (/Users/andreas/Desktop/MFC/target/classes started by andreaspichler in /Users/andreas/Desktop/MFC)
2022-09-01 21:15:06.524  INFO 39924 --- [           main] com.example.mfc.MfcApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-09-01 21:15:07.278  INFO 39924 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9001 (http)
2022-09-01 21:15:07.285  INFO 39924 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-09-01 21:15:07.286  INFO 39924 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2022-09-01 21:15:07.350  INFO 39924 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-09-01 21:15:07.350  INFO 39924 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 783 ms
2022-09-01 21:15:07.381  WARN 39924 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dynamoDBController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dynamoDBRepository' defined in file [/Users/andreas/Desktop/MFC/target/classes/com/example/mfc/DynamoDBRepository.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
2022-09-01 21:15:07.382  INFO 39924 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-09-01 21:15:07.391  INFO 39924 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-09-01 21:15:07.405 ERROR 39924 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dynamoDBController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dynamoDBRepository' defined in file [/Users/andreas/Desktop/MFC/target/classes/com/example/mfc/DynamoDBRepository.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at com.example.mfc.MfcApplication.main(MfcApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dynamoDBRepository' defined in file [/Users/andreas/Desktop/MFC/target/classes/com/example/mfc/DynamoDBRepository.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1232) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1326) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger cannot be cast to class java.util.logging.Logger (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.util.logging.Logger is in module java.logging of loader 'bootstrap')
    at com.example.mfc.DynamoDBRepository.<clinit>(DynamoDBRepository.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    ... 39 common frames omitted

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58138', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Exception says:

```
ClassCastException : class ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger cannot be cast to class java.util.logging.Logger (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.util.logging.Logger is in module java.logging of loader 'bootstrap')
```

This is happening as in class DynamoDBRepository slf4j LoggerFactory is used to get Logger which is trying to cast into java.util.logging.Logger
Replace java.util.logging.Logger with org.slf4j.Logger

Answer (score 0):

Caused by:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger cannot be cast to class java.util.logging.Logger (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.util.logging.Logger is in module java.logging of loader 'bootstrap')
```